# Create Django HTML Button that will Change BooleanField in Model

Tags: django

I am a beginner with Django and am hoping to get pointed in the right direction. I am building a webapp that has job postings on it, and I would like to have an "Accept this job" button on each job description page that will change a BooleanField I defined in the model to True. This way, no other users may be able to take on the job. Are there any suggestions? My database is SQLite.

Comment: => [pointing inthe right direction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: ps: removed irrelevant tags.